# How do i Change the cat class to support the extra members i have, and how do i make an array of cats

Tags: c#

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Cat
    {
        public string name;
        public double[] position

        public void setName(string desiredname)
        {
            name = desiredname;
        }
        public void setPosition()
        {
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            position = new double[3];
            position[0] = rnd1.NextDouble();
            position[1] = rnd1.NextDouble();
            position[2] = rnd1.NextDouble();

        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cat Cat1 = new Cat();
            Cat1.setName("Jawaharal");
            Cat1.setPosition();
            Console.WriteLine("Cat1" + Cat1.name + " " + Cat1.position[0] + Cat1.position[1] + Cat1.position[2]);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to make an array of cats and how to set properties and execute methods

```
public class Cat
{
    private string name;
    public Cat(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string SayName()
    {
        return $"Meow my name is {name}";
    }
}

// fixed size array
var cats = new Cat[3];
cats[0] = new Cat("pete");
cats[1] = new Cat("dave");
cats[2] = new Cat("mike");


//dynamic size array
var cats = new List<Cat>();
cats.Add(new Cat("pete"));
cats.Add(new Cat("dave"));
cats.Add(new Cat("mike"));

var catArray = cats.ToArray();
```

Hope this answers your question! Cheers!